# Mass Webinar Google Calendar Invite

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is it possible to send a lot of google calendar invites to people have registered for a webinar?

A lot of people, like 30k per week?

I know it can be done for a small scale, 200-500 or so, but I'd like to figure out if this can be done using the cloud console or something?

When I run tests in make.com, google states that we have "abused" the api.

Can we pay for it?

Help / guidance to a solution that I can use with make.com.